# Which way to go with twisted and web-programming?

Tags: python, django, twisted, twisted.web, nevow

So, I programmed this twisted application a few months ago, which I now would like to extend with a web-based user interface for configuration.

The Twisted website recommends Nevow, but I am not really sure if this is a good choice. Their website is down for a while it seems and their launchpad page hadn't seen any update in half a year. Is this project dead?
Additionally I have seen discussion of moving parts of Nevow into twisted.web on the twisted-web mailinglist. So, is it still recommended for new developments?

Another idea was using Django. I would need user authentication and permissions anyway in the config-interface, and I am quite familiar with it. (I have never worked with Nevow or twisted.web)
But it seems quite difficult to interface both worlds, all I could find were examples of running Django with WSGI in Twisted.

Are there any other possibilities to have a slick looking user interface on top of twisted?

Comment: Have you investigated CherryPy yet?

Comment: The [BuildBot](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/ScreenShots) tool is written with Twisted and has some nice web page outputs, it might be a good place to learn from.

Answer (score 9):

First, let me address the perception that Nevow is dead.  The launchpad project containing the code for Nevow (and the rest of the Divmod projects) is [divmod.org on launchpad](http://launchpad.net/divmod.org).  A hardware failure has badly impacted the project's public presence, but it's still there, and other things (like the wiki and the tickets) are in the process of being recovered.  There isn't a lot of active maintenance work going on right now, but that's mostly because it's good enough for most of its users; there are lots of people who depend on Nevow and would be very upset if it stopped working.  Those people have the skills and experience necessary to continue maintaining it.  So, while it's not being actively promoted right now, I think it's unlikely that it's going to go away.

My long-term hope for Nevow would be as follows.  (I'd say "plan", but since I haven't been actively involved with its maintenance lately, this is really up to those who are.)  First, I'd like to extract its templating facilities and move them into twisted.web.  The clean, non-deprecated API for Nevow is mostly covered by [nevow.page.Element](http://python.net/crew/mwh/nevowapi/nevow.page.Element.html) and the various [loaders](http://python.net/crew/mwh/nevowapi/nevow.loaders.html).  Twisted itself wants to generate HTML in a few places and these facilities could be useful.  Then we should throw out the "appserver" and resource-model parts of Nevow.  Those are mostly just a random collection of bugfixes or alterations for twisted.web, most of which were present in some form in twisted.web2 and will therefore either be rolled back into twisted.web anyway, or have already been applied there.  Finally there's the question of Athena.  While two-way communication is one of Twisted's strengths, Athena is itself a gigantic, sprawling JavaScript codebase and should probably remain its own project.

Third, on to the main question, given this information, what should you do now?

Generally speaking, I'd say, "use nevow".  The project has some warts, it needs more documentation and its API needs to be trimmed to eliminate some old and broken stuff, but it's still quite useful and very much alive.  To make up for the slightly sparse documentation, you can join the `#divmod` or `#twisted.web` channels on Freenode to get help with it.  If you help out by contributing patches where you can, you will find that you'll get a lot of enthusiastic help there.   When you ignore the deprecated parts Nevow has a pretty small, sane, twisted friendly API.  The consequence of the plan for Nevow's evolution that I outlined above are actually pretty minimal.  If it even happens at all, what it means for *you* is, in 1-5 years, when you upgrade to a new version of Twisted, you'll get a couple of deprecation warnings, change some `import` lines in your code from `from nevow.page import ...; from nevow.loaders import ...` to some hypothetical new thing like `from twisted.web.page.element import ...; from twisted.web.page.templates import ...`, or somesuch.  Most of the API past that point should remain the same, and definitely the high-level concepts shouldn't change much.

The main advantage that you get from using Nevow is that it's async-friendly and can render pages in your main thread without blocking things.  Plus, you can then get really easy COMET for free with Athena.

You can also use Django.  This is not quite as async-friendly but it obviously does have a broader base of support.  However, "not as async friendly" doesn't mean "hard to use".  You can run it in twisted.web via [WSGIResource](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.web.wsgi.WSGIResource.html), [and simply use blockingCallFromThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.html) in your Django application to invoke any Twisted API that returns a Deferred, which should be powerful enough to do just about anything you want.  If you have a more specific question about how to instantiate Twisted web resources to combine Twisted Web and Django, you should probably ask it in its own Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 6):

Nevow is still a good choice if you want support for Deferreds in the templating system you use (it's not dead).  It also has a few advantages over plain Twisted Web when it comes to complicated URL dispatch.  However, it is **basically** just a templating system.  Twisted Web is the real web server.  So either way, you're going to use Twisted Web.  In fact, even if you use Django in Twisted Web's WSGI container, you're still going to use Twisted Web.  So learning things about Twisted Web isn't going to hurt you.

If you're going to be generating any amount of HTML, then you very much want to use an HTML templating library.  By this point no one should be constructing HTML using primitive string operations.  So if you want to use one of the other Python HTML templating libraries out there - Cheetah, Quixote, etc - instead of Nevow, that's great!  You're just going to use the templating library to get a string to write out in response to an HTTP request.  Twisted Web doesn't care where the string came from.

And if you do want to do something with Django (or another WSGI-based system), then you can certainly deploy this in your Twisted process using Twisted Web's WSGI support.  And you can still interact between the WSGI applications and the rest of your Twisted code, as long as you exercise a little care - WSGI applications run in a thread pool, and Twisted APIs are not thread-safe, you have to invoke them with [`reactor.callFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.html#callFromThread) or one of the small number of similar APIs (in particular, [`blockingCallFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#blockingCallFromThread) is sometimes a useful higher-level tool to use).

Answer (score 1):

At this point Nevow is definitively dead. As illustration of how dead it is, there is a [bug that prevents installation of Nevow using pip](https://bugs.launchpad.net/tahoe-lafs/+bug/812537), which was fixed on trunk in 2009, but it isn't in any release because there has been no release since then.

twisted.web and in particular twisted.web.template cover pretty much all of what was useful in Nevow, and should be used for any new project that was considering using Nevow.

Comment: At the time I wrote this, Nevow was dead, however, there has since been a release (0.11.1). This was mainly to fix packaging problems for existing projects that depend on it, and I still would not recommend using it for new development.

Comment: do you have any alternatives for async web development as in 2018?