# Form based authentication with twisted.web

Tags: authentication, twisted

Can anybody point me to a simple example about how to implement form based authentication with twisted.web? I only found http://blog.vrplumber.com/index.php?/archives/1640-Adding-user-authentication-to-your-Twisted-web-site-Another-HowTo-for-undocumented-features....html which seems to be quite old.

Update: As Jean-Paul asked for, I'll try to be a bit more specific. I'm looking for a simple starting point, which allows me to use my own user database to check credentials. So idealy I would like to have some module or library, which handels secure cookies, storing and checking salted passwords, ... which can easily be integrated into twisted. Just imagine you have a small web app where you can register for an account and login afterwards. How would you do something like that with Twisted. No fancy "enterprise" requirements like AD or so.

Comment: This question would probably benefit from being made somewhat more specific.  As it stands, your question probably calls for a several page answer, with discussion of a number of different options (which the answerer will have to make a guess at, since your question doesn't specific whether you're concerned with cookie management, persistent sessions, cred integration, the specific details of authentication crypto, or any of a number of other issues that need to be addressed for "form based authentication with twisted.web").  Perhaps you can pick one part of your overall problem to focus on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Web Application Development](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-development.html) section of the Twisted Documentation. Also, if you haven't already, you should look through some of Twisted's [example code](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/examples/index.html).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840444/which-way-to-go-with-twisted-and-web-programming) may also be of help you. It seems you can go a number of ways when it comes to programming a web application on top of Twisted -- [Nevow](https://launchpad.net/nevow) and [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) being the two mentioned in the thread. Twisted's documentation also mentions that you might use Nevow.

Comment: The webguard.py example looks like what I was looking for.